# what is the nature of strokes of 爫

Tags: handwriting, stroke-order, strokes

爫 is written in a different way than 爪 when it is used as a component in a character.
I would be sure that 丿 piě  丶 diǎn 丶 diǎn 丿 piě is the correct draw.
爪 is written 丿 piě  丿 piě   丨 shù  ㇏ nà    according to archchinese.com

Is there a usefull website where the strokes for most common components are described  ?

Comment: Not pretty sure about simplified Chinese, but there is a website for traditional Chinese maintained by the Taiwanese government. https://dict.mini.moe.edu.tw/SearchIndex/word_detail?wordID=D0001193&breadcrumbs=Search_%E7%88%AA_one&dictSearchField=%E7%88%AA

Comment: they have no result for 爫  :-(  and they give 小  for ⺍   !   very strange taiwanese website...

Comment: Of course, because 爫 is not a complete word... You should search for a word that has 爫.

Comment: my website 打有 gives  采，菜，浮，觅，乳， 受，滔，妥，摇，遥，谣，印 (in that one 爫 is turned 90 °).  your website doesn't give the nature of stroke, if the last in 爫, on the right, is a 丿 piě or a  丶 diǎn.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

It is written differently in its radical form indeed, as it often happens with radicals.

Another website showing decompositions is Wiktionary, e.g.: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%88%AB

According to Wiktionary, in Mainland China, Hong Kong, Taiwan and Vietnam (see the GHTV mark):
爫 = ⿱丿⺍
⺍ = ⿲丶丶丿
=> 爫 = ⿱丿⿲丶丶丿

While in Japan and Korea (JK for Japan and Korea):
爫 = ⿱丿⿲丿丶丶

So, depending on the country,
爫 is either 丿丶丶丿 (in GHTV)
or 丿丿丶丶 (in JK).

This is unfortunately normal situation: stroke order differs not only between radical and standalone forms but also from country to country.
In English there are differences in spelling, too, e.g.: threater vs. theatre.

**Update on 爫 = ⿱丿⺍**
Wiktionary does say this, but the character is not displayed correctly due to browser-unicode-font limitations. See the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: yes ! this website is normally very useful !  but in that case, they write :  " 爫 (radical 87, 爪+0, 4 strokes, cangjie input 竹火 (HF) or X竹火 (XHF), composition ⿱丿(GHTV) or ⿱丿⿲丿丶丶(JK)) "   giving below the first 丿 piě  another  丿 piě  followed by two 丶 diǎn   :('  i am puzzled

Comment: According to Wiktionary, in Mainland China, Hong Kong, Taiwan and Vietnam (see the GHTV mark):   
爫 = ⿱丿⺍ .   

⺍ = ⿲丶丶丿.    

=> 爫 = ⿱丿⿲丶丶丿.  


While in Japan and Korea (JK for Japan and Korea):  

爫 = ⿱丿⿲丿丶丶.  


So, depending on the country,   

爫 is either 丿丶丶丿 (in GHTV)   

or 丿丿丶丶 (in JK).   
  

This is unfortunately normal situation: stroke order differs not only between radical and standalone forms but also from country to country.  
In English there are differences in spelling, too, e.g.: threater vs. theatre.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The website https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/爫 doesn't give 爫 = ⿱丿⺍ . ⺍ = ⿲丶丶丿. => 爫 = ⿱丿⿲丶丶丿  but i think in mainland China   丶丶丿 is the right writing  :-)

Comment: Wiktionary actually does say this, but the character is not displayed correctly due to browser-unicode-font limitations. Updated the answer above with the screenshot.
Also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%AD%95%84 says ⿲丶丶丿